# Mysql exception from execute timeout

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have the following java code fragment:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString, user, password);
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
                                      java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
stmt.setMaxRows(100);
stmt.setQueryTimeout(2);

try {
    stmt.execute("SELECT SLEEP(100)"); // (1)
} finally {
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();
}
```

It is designed to simulate a long running query that will time out. However, it raises an exception that is not the expected one:

> Streaming result set com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic@ is still
>   active. No statements may be issued when any streaming result sets are
>   open and in use on a given connection. Ensure that you have called
>   .close() on any active streaming result sets before attempting more
>   queries. java.sql.SQLException: Streaming result set
>   com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic@ is still active. No
>   statements may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and
>   in use on a given connection. Ensure that you have called .close() on
>   any active streaming result sets before attempting more queries.

Looking closer, it appears the error happens as the close method attempts to reset the `MaxRows` to its default value. However, if I replace line (1) with

```
stmt.executeQuery("SELECT SLEEP(100)");
```

The proper exception, `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLTimeoutException` is raised.

I would like to run execute, stream the results, have a limit on the number of rows, and not have this error crop up. Any suggestions?

Comment: The problem - afaik - is that you don't process the result set returned. You need to get the result set before you can do anything else like closing the statement.